# how to have windows.location.href response act as a promise

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I'm using implicit grant flow in angular 4 where the recommended approach is to set windows.location.href to the auth provider url.

Can I create a promise from windows.location.href so I know to trigger a follow-up action once the promise returns?

If a promise isn't an option are there alternatives?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No.  Adjusted my design, but no real work-around found.